# section attribute of a function template is silently ignored in GCC

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, attributes

I'm trying to put a specific set of functions into a separate section and got trouble doing it with GCC.

```
namespace /* anonymous */ {
  [[gnu::section(".mysection")]]
  void regular_func() { }

  template <class T>
  [[gnu::section(".mysection")]]
  void template_func() { }
} // namespace /* anonymous */

void (*ptr1)() = &regular_func;
void (*ptr2)() = &template_func<int>;
```

With clang, the symbols for both of `regular_func` and `template_func<int>` are placed in `.mysection` as I expected.

```
$ clang++ -std=c++14 a.cpp -c && objdump -t a.o | grep -E "regular|template"
0000000000000000 l     F .mysection 0000000000000006 _ZN12_GLOBAL__N_112regular_funcEv
0000000000000010 l     F .mysection 0000000000000006 _ZN12_GLOBAL__N_113template_funcIiEEvv
```

But with GCC, the function template is not placed in `.mysection`, but in the `.text.*` section.

```
$ g++ -std=c++14 a.cpp -c && objdump -t a.o | grep -E "regular|template"
0000000000000000 l     F .mysection 0000000000000007 _ZN12_GLOBAL__N_112regular_funcEv
0000000000000000 l     F .text  0000000000000007 _ZN12_GLOBAL__N_113template_funcIiEEvv
```

I'm using clang-3.7.1 and gcc-5.3.0.

How can I force gcc to put the template-instantiated function in a separate section?

Comment: Filed a bug : https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=70435

Answer (score 3):

It may be small comfort, but GCC will oblige if you apply the `section`
attribute to an explicit instantiation of `template <class T> void template_func()`,
for each `T` that you want to be instantiated, e.g.

```
namespace /* anonymous */ {
    [[gnu::section(".mysection")]]
    void regular_func() { }

    template <class T>
    void template_func() { }

    template [[gnu::section(".mysection")]] void template_func<int>();

} // namespace /* anonymous */


void (*ptr1)() = &regular_func;
void (*ptr2)() = &template_func<int>;
```

Then:

```
$ g++ -std=c++14 a.cpp -c && objdump -C -t a.o | grep -E "regular|template"
0000000000000000 l     F .mysection 0000000000000007 (anonymous namespace)::regular_func()
0000000000000007 l     F .mysection 0000000000000007 void (anonymous namespace)::template_func<int>()
```

Unfortunately *clang* rejects:

```
template [[gnu::section(".mysection")]] void template_func<int>();
```

saying:

```
template [[gnu::section(".mysection")]] void template_func<int>();
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
error: an attribute list cannot appear here
```

so each compiler must have its own way, via conditional compilation.

Moreover this fix brings the added headache that you must somehow ensure
that `template_func()` can't be instantated for any `T` that you haven't explicitly
instantiated.

You may achieve that by statically asserting in the function template's body that
`T` is one of types `A,B,C...` that you allow to be instantiated. Then if it
is ever instantiated with `T` = `D`, the `static_assert` will fire; you can
add `D` to the list and add an explicit instantiation for `D`:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T, typename First>
constexpr bool is_in()
{
    return std::is_same<T,First>::value;
}

template<typename T, typename First, typename Second, typename ...Rest>
constexpr bool is_in()
{
    return is_in<T,First>() || is_in<T,Second,Rest...>();
}

namespace /* anonymous */ {
    [[gnu::section(".mysection")]]
    void regular_func() { }

    template <class T>
    void template_func() 
    {
        static_assert(is_in<T,int,float>(),"");
    }

    template [[gnu::section(".mysection")]] void template_func<int>();
    template [[gnu::section(".mysection")]] void template_func<float>();

} // namespace /* anonymous */


void (*ptr1)() = &regular_func;
void (*ptr2)() = &template_func<int>;
void (*ptr3)() = &template_func<float>;
void (*ptr4)() = &template_func<char>; // <-- static_assert fails
```

Comment: It's interesting that the attribute is honored for explicit instantiation but unfortunately it's not an option for me. I simplified the parameter as a single type T in the example but it actually is variadic parameters, so I cannot manually instantiate it for all possible combinations.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant way to do things but you can do some name mangling and modify the linker script to get the desired behavior

```
#define TEMPLATE_SECTION(name, section) name##_##section##_

#define template_func TEMPLATE_SECTION(template_func, mysection)

template<class T>
void template_func() { }

void regular_func() {} 

int main() {
    regular_func();         //placed in ".text"
    template_func<int>();   //placed in ".mysection"
    template_func<float>(); //placed in ".mysection"
    return 0;
}
```

And in the linker script

```
SECTIONS {
    .mysection : {
        *(*_mysection_*) 
    }

    .text : {
        *(.text .text.*)
    }
}
```