# GCC section attribute ignored in a templated function

Tags: c++, gcc, attributes, sections

I'm tracking down a rather sneaky bug that occurred when I added a template parameter to one of my classes. During initialization, it was placing a static local variable in a certain section of memory.

It seems that GCC's section attribute is just ignored when used within a templated function/class. My problem sounds similar to what [this user was facing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36279162/section-attribute-of-a-function-template-is-silently-ignored-in-gcc). However, I can't see that the proposed workaoround applies to my case.

I've put together a very simple example that demonstrates this. Consider this piece of code:

```
void handler_func() { }

using handler_type = void(*)();

struct S { handler_type handler; };

template <typename T>
void templated()
{
    static S __attribute__((section(".templ_section"))) __attribute__((used)) templ_instance {handler_func};
}

void free()
{
    static S __attribute__((section(".free_section"))) __attribute__((used)) free_instance {handler_func};
}

struct Foo{};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    templated<Foo>();

    free();
}
```

My hope was that the `templ_instance` would be placed in the `.templ_section` and the `free_instance` would be placed in the `.free_section`.

However, this is the location of the variables with GCC:

```
0000000000000000 l     O .free_section  0000000000000008 _ZZ4freevE13free_instance
0000000000000000 l    d  .data.rel.local._ZZ9templatedI3FooEvvE14templ_instance 0000000000000000 .data.rel.local._ZZ9templatedI3FooEvvE14templ_instance
0000000000000000 u     O .data.rel.local._ZZ9templatedI3FooEvvE14templ_instance 0000000000000008 _ZZ9templatedI3FooEvvE14templ_instance
```

and this what Clang does:

```
0000000000000000 l     O .free_section  0000000000000008 _ZZ4freevE13free_instance
0000000000000000  w    O .templ_section 0000000000000008 _ZZ9templatedI3FooEvvE14templ_instance
```

I can't believe this is expected behaviour in GCC. Is there any way around this?

Comment: In real life, does the type of `templ_instance`depend on the template type `T`?

Comment: It does not, however, handler function is a function within the templated class.

Answer (score 1):

If it happens that the type of `templ_instance` does not depend on the template type `T`, you can workaround that by having that object in a free function:

```
S& templated_impl()
{
    static S __attribute__((section(".templ_section"))) __attribute__((used)) templ_instance {nullptr};
    return templ_instance;
}

template <typename T>
void templated()
{
    static S& templ_instance = templated_impl();
    templ_instance = { handler_func };
}
```

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/8fZFWG)

#### GCC (8.x)

```
  .zero 8
  .section .free_section,"aw"
  .align 8
  .type free()::free_instance, @object
  .size free()::free_instance, 8
free()::free_instance:
  .quad handler_func()
  .section .templ_section,"aw"  // BINGO!
  .align 8
  .type templated_impl()::templ_instance, @object
  .size templated_impl()::templ_instance, 8
templated_impl()::templ_instance:
```

#### Clang (7.x)

```
  .size void templated<Foo>(), .Lfunc_end4-void templated<Foo>()
  .cfi_endproc
  .type templated_impl()::templ_instance,@object # @templated_impl()::templ_instance
  .section .templ_section,"aw",@progbits
  .p2align 3
templated_impl()::templ_instance:
  .quad handler_func()
  .size templated_impl()::templ_instance, 8

  .type free()::free_instance,@object # @free()::free_instance
  .section .free_section,"aw",@progbits
  .p2align 3
free()::free_instance:
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. This does indeed help in placing the struct in the correct section. However, the struct contains a function pointer to an event handler, and in my case I wan't that to point to a function in my class template. And of course function templates don't have an address until they're expanded. So the handler just ends up being null... Am I trying to do something impossible here?