# Is it possible to access a variable template without the template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates

I am not sure if this is viable. I want to initialize a variable template inside a constructor of my class.

```cpp
template<typename T>
T var_tem;

Struct A {
  template<typename U>
  A(U u) { var_tem<U> = u;}
};
```

I am wondering if it's possible to access `var_tem<U>` later without knowing the type `U`. Also, I know whenever I access `var_tem<>`, only one instantiation exists. This would be much easier if I make my class hold `var_tem` as member data. But I have other methods I would rather not make templates due to issues discussed here [section attribute of a function template is silently ignored in GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36279162/section-attribute-of-a-function-template-is-silently-ignored-in-gcc). Basically, I have some internal static data needed to be emitted to a specific section.

Comment: Depending on the use case you may be able to make the whole `A` struct a template and use CTAD to deduce the template parameter without having to explicitly specify it. If this is not an option, things will get ugly; there's no way the compiler can tell during compilation that you're only ever specializing the constructor with a single parameter in all translation units, let alone which template parameter was used by some other part of the code which could be part of a different translation unit. This sounds like an XY problem though. Could you elaborate on the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: No, it's not possible. There isn't a single `var_tem` variable - there's an infinite number of them, one for each type. Whenever you access one of them, you need to specify which one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information of the type `U` is not available after the call to constructor. However, at the point of access, you also need to be aware of the type, otherwise you wouldn't know what you can do with it. So either you specify the type directly, or you're passing a visitor.

Now, for visitors, as long as there's a compile-time limited set of signatures, it's doable. All you need is to enumerate these types and have a type switch (and store the pointer to the variable):

```
template<typename T>
T var_tem;

Struct A {
  template<typename U>
  A(U u)
  {
    var_tem<U> = u;
    var = &var_tem<U>;
  }

  void tryVisit() {}

  template<typename V, typename T, typename... Ts>
  void tryVisit(V& v)
  {
    if (var == &var_tem<T>) {
      v(*static_cast<T*>(var));
    } else {
      tryVisit<V, Ts...>(v);
    }
  }
    }
  }

private:
  void* var;
};
```

If listing the types is not an option, there's one more possibility, but it's only recommended for error handlers: you might throw it as an exception. Exception handlers are chainable, so you don't need a specific point at which you have all the possible types (but handlers are still listed on the stack). Note that you can only handle specific types this way, there are no template exception handlers. The throw function can then be stored as an `std::function<void(void)>`:

```
template<typename T>
T var_tem;

Struct A {
  template<typename U>
  A(U u)
  : throwTheVar([]() { throw var_tem<U>; })
  { var_tem<U> = u; }

  void throwAsError() { throwTheVar(); }

private:
  std::function<void()> throwTheVar;
};
```

If it's not an error handler, then I wouldn't suggest throw; but you might still populate a limited interface of `std::function<>`s using this lambda logic. The problem with it is that it's very slow: internally, `std::function<>` is either a virtual or a function pointer, depending on your implementation.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, typo, thanks for spotting!

Comment: `std::function` serves no purpose here; the lambda used is always captureless so a simple function pointer would suffice.

Comment: As an aside, please use `()` rather than `(void)` for nullary functions – this is a legacy C-ism that serves no purpose in C++ except to potentially confuse readers that do not also know C. (And even C itself is dropping this silliness in C23.)

Comment: @ildjarn Changed accordingly.